# Handling extra data to store for each model attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on an application where I want the user to be able to enter notes associated to any input field. For example, a user may type in a value for a field named `Price`, and add a note next to it to specify that it is negotiable under certain conditions.

The solutions I have considered are:

- Creating two attributes for each field (e.g. `Price` and `PriceNote`)
- Creating a new class (e.g. `Field`) containing a `Value` and a `Note`, then changing all model properties to that `Field` type.

There are downsides to both of these solutions, though. Creating additional attributes would bloat the code and make modifications awkward, while creating an extra class would require typecasting field values constantly and handling editors/displays manually in the views.

Is there a better, more elegant solution?

Comment: Prototype it! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping

Comment: *There are downsides to both of these solutions, though.* - If I had a nickel for every time I said that, I'd probably have enough money to quit my job and live comfortably for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to create a `Dictionary<string, string>` in the model to store notes, with keys set using `nameof(MyAttribute)`. Notes will have to be retrieved with `TryGetValue()`, but it is less awkward than constantly typecasting or duplicating fields, and it is easily accessible from views.

Model:

```
public virtual IDictionary<string, string> Notes { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes[nameof(model.MyAttribute)], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

If I need to manipulate the note:

```
string myNote;
if (MyModel.Notes.TryGetValue(nameof(MyModel.MyAttribute), out myNote))
{
    // Do something with the note
}
else
{
    // There is no note for the given attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the backend looks like, but you could create a object that looks like this:

```
{ProductId: 123,
ProductName:'Widget',
Price:200.00,
minQuantity: 10,
Comments:[
    Price: "can be reduced blah blah",
    minQuantity: "N/A on orders > 1000"
]
}
```

This way - you can access price/minQuantity the same way you always would, and Comments are stored in a simple string/string dictionary.

You could also cache those comments in a totally different call ... So you pull them separately from the actual object definition.

**Data Storage**

Again, depending on your db, you could store comments as json in a text field, or you could store them normalized in a table that has `ObjectType,EntityId,FieldName,Comment` in it. Up to you, but I'm guessing you don't need them in "every" table -- just occasionally want to add label/comments to fields.

Let me know the middle tier (eg - c#) and maybe we can turn that json into an actual class in your middle tier.

```
public interface IProduct {
    string ProductId {get; set; }
    string ProductName {get; set; }
    Double Price {get; set; }
    int minQuantity {get; set; }
    Dictionary<string,string> Comments {get; set; }
}
```

As a simple example.

**Finally, in Angular/Controller**

For the front end, you could create a simple property that returns the correct comment:

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="Price" /><p>{{getComments("Price")}}</p>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getComments = function(fieldNm) {
   if($scope.product==undefined 
       || $scope.product.Comments.length==0) {
       || $scope.product.Comments.hasOwnProperty(fieldNm)==false) {
      return '';
   }
   return $scope.product.Comments[fieldNm];
}
```

Or, you could create a directive to accomplish the same thing universally (so you don't have to repeat code in several controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using a `Dictionary`. Because your examples are in a different programming language (I recommend you check the question tags), your answer does not correspond to the question enough for me to accept your answer, but it has allowed me to reach a satisfying solution.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!  Just FYI - the interface is c# and the json is what that interface would serialize into in json.  The html is just angularJs (wasnt sure what you were using, but wanted to give an example).  Dont worry about upvoting at all ... others will if they find it useful.  Glad you are making progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a class structure like this

```
public class Field
{
    private string Value;
    private string Comment;
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private Field Price { get; set; }
    private Field SomeOtherFiled { get; set; }
}
```

One downside will be to access the value you'll have to do Price.Value or for comment Price.Comment (but it makes sense logically anyway)